# How does Java implement lock

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, locking

I often use some Java mechanism for handling multithreading problem such as `AtomicInteger`, `synchronized` ...

My question is: How Java can implement those lock mechanism? My mean is: when implementing, Java will meet multithreading problem too, and how can they deal with. Does all operating system have lock mechanism and Java just simply call their API.

Comment: _Does all operating system have lock mechanism and Java just simply call their API_ - In short: yes.

Comment: And the next question would then be: what about the OS, then the OS would have to solve the concurrency problem. Answer: Yes - and it uses special features of the CPU to do this.

Comment: And, going a level deeper, most server/workstation/laptop/mobile-device microprocessors have hardware support for locking that is used by the operating system.

Comment: If you want to dive in and learn how it really works, this is a great book to learn from:  https://www.amazon.com/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/dp/0123973376/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of locks in Java is specific to the instruction set of the Java platform.  For example, with x86, it *might* use the CMPXCHG instruction - atomic compare and exchange - at the lowest level to implement the fast path of the lock.  The CMPXCHG instruction is a [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instruction that guarantees atomic memory access at the hardware level.

If the thread cannot acquire the lock immediately, then it could "spinlock" or it could perform a syscall to schedule a different thread.  Different strategies are used depending on the platform, JVM switches, etcetera.

---

Note that in any language that implements (efficient) locking, there is a bit of "black magic" to implement it.  This could be an assembler coded library, or some smarts in the native code compiler that knows to inject special instructions for certain bytecodes or "intrinsic" method calls.

Comment: So for implementing lock mechanism, Java will use two ways:
1. implement their own algorithm (as you have mentioned)
2. use OS API (as some comments on my question)
Is my assumption right ?

Comment: Yes.  Those are the alternatives.